# Encrypt main data Linux partition so it's only accessed by unique system

Tags: debian, encryption, usb-drive

How can i encrypt a Linux internal disk, so that it is only accessible with a unique system (preinstalled Debian bullseye), installed on a USB drive?
Even if someone has the encryption passphrase and physical access, without the USB drive holding the other system he shouldn't be able to access it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> only to an unique system (preinstalled Debian bullseye) installed on the USB drive even if someone have the encryption passphrase

**Nope.** In cryptography, safety of encryption is always provided by the secrecy of the key, *never* by not giving someone the decryption software. And in the end, that's what you demand: only the right software can decrypt your drive.

However, I think a slight rephrasing of your question allows us to answer this positively.

> Can I put a decryption key on a USB drive, so that only the person holding that USB drive can decrypt?

Yes, that's pretty standard. Simply follow [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition/90911#90911) of the many guides on how to put LUKS keys on an external USB drive, and you're fine.

Also note that anything that's stored on a USB drive can be copied – a USB drive is just "stupid" storage. So, if you need something that is uncopyable, then this is not a solution, either.

You'll need a uncloneable crypto device (i.e., a device that contains the key itself, and does the decryption internally, never giving out the key itself) which would then allow you to ensure decryption access can never be given away without giving away the card. (unless you allow anyone to change the settings of your drive encryption, because then they could just add another key... but that's another thing.)

This then becomes a bit specific to the kind of device you want to use (nitrokey, TPM2 devices, FIDO keys...), but "LUKS + {device name}" would be the terms to search for.

Comment: Would using an encrypted USB drive (like Kingston Ironkey) aid in the security of the LUKS key?

Comment: I don't know what these do, but probably not. It would just add another thing you would need to tell people to be able to *use* your system, but once they have that, they can still copy stuff.

Comment: There's always hiring an armed guard to protect the USB key. Of course, you'll have to hire somebody to protect the guard. How much security does the OP really need?

Comment: @doneal24 has a point. Giving someone physical access to a machine and the key, in whichever form, to decrypt the data, you're giving them full, root-level access to the data forever, unless you really know how to secure your system from power on to power off (secure boot, encrypted drives, physical protection against booting anything from USB, which is coincidentally what you're proposing to do...).